# jQuery OEmbed Plugin - Error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, plugins

I'm currently using the following jQuery plugin: jQuery  OEmbed.  This plugin works great in FF, Chrome, and Safari.  However, I am having an issue in IE7.  I have stripped my code down to very bare-bones, but still can't figure out what would be causing the following error:

```
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.
```

The line the error is referring to is:

```
  $("#container").oembed("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nue4pvzuyOo");
```

Here is my HTML (again, very basic):

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
    <title>jquery-oembed explicit insert example</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="oe.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#container").oembed("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nue4pvzuyOo");

    });
  </script>
 <div id="container"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The javascript for the plugin can be found [here](http://jsbin.com/uzemu/).

Interestingly enough, this error does NOT occur in IE8-- only IE7.

Any ideas on what might be causing this error?

Comment: +1 for concise, self-contained and useful question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JSLint](http://jslint.com/) reports that, among other problems, the plugin code you linked to has an extra comma inside an object literal. Correcting this seems to fix it in IE7.

The fix:

```
// Plugin defaults
$.fn.oembed.defaults = {
    maxWidth: null,
    maxHeight: null,
            embedMethod: "replace", // "auto", "append", "fill"
};
```

changes to:

```
// Plugin defaults
$.fn.oembed.defaults = {
    maxWidth: null,
    maxHeight: null,
            embedMethod: "replace" // "auto", "append", "fill"
};
```

Note the comma after `"replace"`.

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/oxitu

Comment: Thanks Brian, that was certainly the issue. Also, thanks for pointing out JSLint.  I'd never heard of that tool before!